# How does a CNN not lose spatial resolution (e.g. for D2-Net)

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am very new to CNNs and one thing i dont understand is why a CNN does not lose its spatial resolution. I stumbled over this at D2-Net, so lets use that for an example:

The input image is 224x224x3. With increasing depth of the network, this turns into 14x14x512. Now I want to use the resulting tensor to do some feature matching (finding correspondings pixels in two images). How can i match those pixels accurately, when the resulting tensor only has a 14x14 spatial resolution?